# CollectionView not loading Xamarin.Forms on load

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Need help regarding CollectionView not loading data from API upon loading. I need to pull-down refresh first before the data will show. I'm doing it MVVM.

Below is my XAML:

```
    <RefreshView   x:DataType="local:MainPageViewModel"  Command="{Binding LoadReleaseDocuments}" 
                       IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing ,Mode=OneWay}"
                        RefreshColor="#FFFF7F50">
        <CollectionView   x:Name="SuccessList"                          
                    ItemsSource="{Binding ReleasedDocuments}"
                    SelectionMode="Single" >
            ...
        </CollectionView>
    </RefreshView>
```

And this is my code behind:

```
    public ObservableCollection<Release> ReleasedDocuments { get; }
    public MainPageViewModel()
    { 
        // collection
        ReleasedDocuments = new ObservableCollection<Release>();

        DeliveredDocuments = new ObservableCollection<Deliver>(); 

        CallNow = new Command<Deliver>(Call_Now);

        //Load
        LoadDocuments = new Command(ExecuteLoadItemsCommand); 
        LoadReleaseDocuments = new Command(ExecuteCommand); 
    }
```

And below code is where I get my data thru API calls

```
    void ExecuteCommand()
    {
        bool forceRefresh = true;

        if (IsRefreshing)
            return;

        IsRefreshing = true;

        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                ReleasedDocuments.Clear();

                switch (Application.Current.Properties["Position"])
                {
                    case string a when a.Contains("Courier"):
                        var items = await DataStore.GetItemsAsync(forceRefresh, Application.Current.Properties["Position"].ToString(), "tmdm");
                        items = items.Where(ab => ab.TMNo != null).Where(ac => ac.TMNo.Contains("DM"));

                        var sortedItems = items.OrderByDescending(c => c.OrderDate);
                        CourierDMData(sortedItems);

                        break;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                IsBusy = false;
                IsRefreshing = false;
                ...
            }
            finally
            {
                IsBusy = false;
                IsRefreshing = false;
            }
        });

        IsRefreshing = false;
    }
```

And inserting it to ObservableCollection

```
    void CourierDMData(IOrderedEnumerable<Summary> sortedItems)
    {
        ReleasedDocuments.Clear();

        foreach (var itemx in sortedItems)
        {
            if (itemx.statusId == 0)
            {
                ReleasedDocuments.Add(new Release()
                {
                    Id = itemx.Id,
                    ....

                });

            }

        }

        CountRelease = ReleasedDocuments.Count;

    }
```

When debugging, I can get the **CountRelease = ReleasedDocuments.Count;** value (count) it is displaying correctly the value, but the CollectionView is not showing anything until I refresh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm usually doing a work around and call refresh with the [PageAppearingEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.page.appearing?view=xamarin-forms) and use [Xamarin Community Toolkit EventToCommandBehavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/behaviors/eventtocommandbehavior) to call a function which calls the refresh function with a small delay if necessary. This way I don't have to manually refresh each time I open the page.

XAML example:

```
<ContentPage.Behaviors>
     <xct:EventToCommandBehavior 
         EventName="Appearing" 
         Command="{Binding AppearingCommand}"/>
</ContentPage.Behaviors>
```

MVVM example:

```
public MyViewModel() //constructor
{
    AppearingCommand = new Command(OnAppearing);
}
public ICommand AppearingCommand { get; }

private void OnAppearing()
{
    await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(int delay); //only if necessary because of initialization
    Refresh(); //Or else set your public properties
}
```